# GPS: Return country name but NOT translated

Tags: android, gps

In my function, I am reading the users location's data:

```
    public async void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        _currentLocation = location;
        Address address = await ReverseGeocodeCurrentLocation();

        Account.Instance.Locality = address.Locality;
        Account.Instance.Country = address.CountryName;
        Account.Instance.CountryCode = address.CountryCode;
    }
```

But the adress and everything is returned in german, since I live in germany. But I need it to be english globally. Is there a better way than to do 210 string comparisons?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you show me your `ReverseGeocodeCurrentLocation` method? If you are using `Geocode` try this `Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Context, Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: Splendid. This did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(Context, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Please refer [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder).